# Appoint a lesson/a meeting

Tags: meaning

Is it possible to use "appoint" in this sense?

> Our teaches appointed a lesson/a meeting for the next day.

I know that "set" is OK, but does "appoint" work?

Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English © 2023

**to fix;set:
to appoint a time for the meeting.**

Comment: If you think of ***appoint*** as having the sense ***select** [from available possibilities]*, it should be more obvious why you can (just about) ***appoint a time** for something to happen*, but you can't naturally ***appoint a meeting** [for tomorrow]*. If it wasn't ***that time***, you could have selected a different time. But if it wasn't ***a meeting***, what alternative could they have "appointed"?

Answer (score 3):

The quote in the original post is wrong, but I sympathise with @user1425 because he has quoted a usage from a dictionary and the replies haven't dealt fully with that quote. In fact, there are three different expressions to consider, and I think the problem is that one of them has been overlooked.

1. **To appoint a meeting**. This is the original post, and the replies correctly point out that meetings are not *appointed*, they are
   *scheduled* or *arranged*.
2. **To appoint a person**. This is a natural usage of *appoint*. People are regularly appointed to a role or responsibility. You can appoint someone as the sports captain, or the manager of the school cafeteria, or the treasurer of the local church.
3. **To appoint a time**. This is the usage that has been overlooked. To *appoint a time at which an activity will take place* is an equally natural English usage. Here are a couple of examples:

- The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/appointed-time) lists several examples of events happening at an appointed time.
- "The Governor-General may appoint such times for holding the sessions of the Parliament as he thinks fit..." (from the [Australian Constitution](https://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Senate/Powers_practice_n_procedures/Odgers_Australian_Senate_Practice/Chapter_07))

So the original post is wrong not because the teachers appointed a meeting (instead of a person). It's wrong because the teachers appointed a meeting rather than a time. This is what the Random House dictionary is saying. So the original post, when correctly edited, might read something like this:

> The teachers appointed the next day as the day of the meeting.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Old Brixtionian is very sufficient. However, I have a few things to add.

'Appoint' refers to the act of giving someone a role. A teacher does not give a day the role of being taught. (This is a confusing sentence, that is why it is incorrect.)

A clearer way to express

> Our teaches appointed a lesson/a meeting for the next day.

would be to say :

> "Our teacher scheduled/organized the meeting for today"

In this version, the teacher is showing their plans for the lesson, not assigning something to it.

Comment: What would you say to this example from a dictionary "to fix; set: to appoint a time for the meeting."

Comment: 'Schedule' is the word. Look at the transitive verb meaning in this link: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schedule

Comment: But you haven't commented on the fact that it is given in a dictionary. Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English © 2023 There is no point in glossing over it.

Answer (score 1):

We tend to appoint ***people***: not ***things***.

Although [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/appoint) has:

"*to determine by authority or agreement; fix; set: to appoint a time for the meeting*",

[Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/appoint) doesn't give that meaning under its "verb" entry, but links to a separate  ["adjective" entry for "appointed"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/appointed).

This suggests that although we say "The appointed meeting," we don't appoint a meeting. This is supported by an [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appointed%20time%2Cappointed%20a%20time%2Cappoint%20a%20lesson%2Cappoint%20a%20meeting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing that - compared with "appointed time" - the expressions "appointed a time", "appoint a lesson" and "appoint a meeting" are rare.

Further down the page at Collins there are interesting differences between the US and UK usages of "appointed".

Comment: But this is from a dictionary "to fix;
set:
to appoint a time for the meeting."

Comment: I can understand the meaning when I read that sentence, but it feels strange to my ears (US English). "Appointing" does indeed mean setting, but almost always appointing to some role, so a person. "appointing a lesson" sounds like flowery, fancier language. I wouldn't expect to hear that in common US English.

Comment: @user1425: Interesting. Thanks. I've edited my answer.

Comment: When you appoint a date or time (for something to happen), you're ***selecting*** a specific date or time from the real-world range of possible values. But you can't meaningfully "appoint" a ***meeting*** or a ***lesson*** from a *range of possible future activities.*